# Random lag when sending data to server UDP

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I am making an app for android. It has to send data byte by byte to the server (don't tell me to send big chunk of data because it won't be useful in my case) which is on the same network. The problem is that it has to be really fast.

Most of the time it's working really well, but there is occasional lag, meaning that it stops sending for a second or two and then everything is sent simultaneously to the server.

I think that this happens because other background apps are trying to send some data as well and then I have to wait in queue for everything to get sent.

If that't why there is occasional lag, please tell me if there is a way to set highest priority for my app or if I can temporarily disable background apps from using the network.
I already tried to disable synchronization by calling `ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(false)` but it didn't fix anything.

If that's not the case, please let me know how I could fix this problem.

I'm using `DatagramSocket` to send data if that helps.

UPDATE:

It's been quite a long time since i asked this question. So because the only way that seemed to fix this was to use TCP instead of UDP I did so with [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) class and used `setTcpNoDelay(true)` on it. It seemed to work at first but when I did more testing I found out that the lag remained.

So, lag decreased but it still happens. Does anyone have any idea now to fix this with TCP?

Comment: Well it could be just that... and there is no way to set your app priority or anything of that matter.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y. Why is your protocol relying on high frequency byte-wise sending of (unreliable!!) UDP packets?

Comment: Because UDP is faster than TCP. and it shouldnt be unreliable if its in the same local network. At least i dont think so.

Comment: Oh, and lag doesn't occur when no other apps are installed on an android device.

Comment: Is this over WiFi or cellular data?

Comment: UDP is unreliable, period, even on the same network. If this is over Wi-Fi, then you must realize that Wi-Fi is a half-duplex medium which requires devices to yield to other devices on the same frequency, even other devices on different networks. Also, collisions may occur, but the sending device cannot detect them (Wi-Fi cannot simultaneously send and listen), and frames will be lost. Every host on the same frequency (same or different network) is equal, and you cannot have one with more priority than another. It may be that your device cannot get a free slot to send for a while.